# Magento order split through observer

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I was wondering if we can split the order on onepage checkout before placing the order? And I want to do it Through observer.

I am using sales_order_place_before event to get the quote and split order.

I have tried to do it in observer like:

```
$productids=array(1,2);
         $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
         $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
         // Start New Sales Order Quote
         $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getId());

         // Set Sales Order Quote Currency
         $quote->setCurrency($order->AdjustmentAmount->currencyID);
         $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                     ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                     ->loadByEmail($email);
         if($customer->getId()==""){
             $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
             $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                     ->setStore($store)
                     ->setFirstname('Jhon')
                     ->setLastname('Deo')
                     ->setEmail($email)
                     ->setPassword("password");
             $customer->save();
         }

         // Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
         $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

             // Configure Notification
         $quote->setSendCconfirmation(1);
         foreach($productsids as $id){
             $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
             $quote->addProduct($product,new Varien_Object(array('qty'   => 1)));
         }

         // Set Sales Order Billing Address
         $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
             'customer_address_id' => '',
             'prefix' => '',
             'firstname' => 'john',
             'middlename' => '',
             'lastname' =>'Deo',
             'suffix' => '',
             'company' =>'',
             'street' => array(
                     '0' => 'Noida',
                     '1' => 'Sector 64'
                 ),
             'city' => 'Noida',
             'country_id' => 'IN',
             'region' => 'UP',
             'postcode' => '201301',
             'telephone' => '78676789',
             'fax' => 'gghlhu',
             'vat_id' => '',
             'save_in_address_book' => 1
         ));

         // Set Sales Order Shipping Address
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
             'customer_address_id' => '',
             'prefix' => '',
             'firstname' => 'john',
             'middlename' => '',
             'lastname' =>'Deo',
             'suffix' => '',
             'company' =>'',
             'street' => array(
                     '0' => 'Noida',
                     '1' => 'Sector 64'
                 ),
             'city' => 'Noida',
             'country_id' => 'IN',
             'region' => 'UP',
             'postcode' => '201301',
             'telephone' => '78676789',
             'fax' => 'gghlhu',
             'vat_id' => '',
             'save_in_address_book' => 1
         ));
         if($shipprice==0){
             $shipmethod='freeshipping_freeshipping';
         }

         // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
         $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                         ->collectShippingRates()
                         ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
                         ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

         // Set Sales Order Payment
         $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));

         // Collect Totals & Save Quote
         $quote->collectTotals()->save();

         // Create Order From Quote
         $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
         $service->submitAll();
         $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();

         // Resource Clean-Up
         $quote = $customer = $service = null;

         // Finished
         return $increment_id;
```

But it is not proceeding further.

Any help with the observer code will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: is it a requirement to do the task on event observer? i have the same requirement but i am trying to do it by rewriting saveorder() function

Comment: Yes that can work if we can rewrite saveorder() but will it work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i have achieved until now
created new module 
installation file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <PMTECH_Splitorder>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </PMTECH_Splitorder>
  </modules>
</config>
```

and here is the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <PMTECH_Splitorder>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </PMTECH_Splitorder>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <splitorder>
        <class>PMTECH_Splitorder_Helper</class>
      </splitorder>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <splitorder>
        <class>PMTECH_Splitorder_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>splitorder_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </splitorder>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <type_onepage>PMTECH_Splitorder_Model_Checkout_Type_Onepage</type_onepage>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

look at the rewrite

```
<checkout>
                    <rewrite>
                        <type_onepage>PMTECH_Splitorder_Model_Checkout_Type_Onepage</type_onepage>
                    </rewrite>
                </checkout>
```

Bellow is the final thing, the extended function

```
<?php
class PMTECH_Splitorder_Model_Checkout_Type_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
{
    /**
     * Create order based on checkout type. Create customer if necessary.
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
     */
    public function saveOrder()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $isNewCustomer = false;
        switch ($this->getCheckoutMethod()) {
            case self::METHOD_GUEST:
                $this->_prepareGuestQuote();
                break;
            case self::METHOD_REGISTER:
                $this->_prepareNewCustomerQuote();
                $isNewCustomer = true;
                break;
            default:
                $this->_prepareCustomerQuote();
                break;
        }

        $cart = $this->getQuote();
        $key=0;
      foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) 
      {
        $key= $key+1;
        $temparray[$key]['product_id']=  $item->getProduct()->getId();
        $temparray[$key]['qty']= $item->getQty();
        $cart->removeItem($item->getId());
        $cart->setSubtotal(0);
        $cart->setBaseSubtotal(0);
        $cart->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
        $cart->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
        $cart->setGrandTotal(0);
        $cart->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

        $cart->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
        $cart->collectTotals();
        }
         $cart->save();

        foreach ($temparray as $key => $item) 
        {
        $customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
        $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
        $quoteObj = $cart;
        $storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($store_id);
        $quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);
        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $productObj = $productModel->load($item['product_id']);
        $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
        $quoteItem->setBasePrice($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteItem->setPriceInclTax($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteItem->setData('original_price', $productObj->getPrice());
        $quoteItem->setData('price', $productObj->getPrice());
        $quoteItem->setRowTotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
        $quoteItem->setQty($item['qty']);
        $quoteItem->setStoreId($store_id);
        $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
        $quoteObj->setBaseSubtotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteObj->setSubtotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteObj->setBaseGrandTotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteObj->setGrandTotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());

        $quoteObj->setStoreId($store_id);
        $quoteObj->collectTotals();
        $quoteObj->save();
        $this->_quote=$quoteObj;

        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);
        $service->submitAll();
        if ($isNewCustomer) {
            try {
                $this->_involveNewCustomer();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
        $this->_checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($quoteObj->getId())
            ->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quoteObj->getId())
            ->clearHelperData();
        $order = $service->getOrder();
        if ($order) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after',
                array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quoteObj));
            $quoteObj->removeAllItems();
            $quoteObj->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
            $quoteObj->collectTotals();
}
            /**
             * a flag to set that there will be redirect to third party after confirmation
             * eg: paypal standard ipn
             */
            $redirectUrl = $this->getQuote()->getPayment()->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl();
            /**
             * we only want to send to customer about new order when there is no redirect to third party
             */
            if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
                try {
                    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::logException($e);
                }
            }
            // add order information to the session
            $this->_checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId())
                ->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl)
                ->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
            // as well a billing agreement can be created
            $agreement = $order->getPayment()->getBillingAgreement();
            if ($agreement) {
                $this->_checkoutSession->setLastBillingAgreementId($agreement->getId());
            }
        }
        // add recurring profiles information to the session
        $profiles = $service->getRecurringPaymentProfiles();
        if ($profiles) {
            $ids = array();
            foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
                $ids[] = $profile->getId();
            }
            $this->_checkoutSession->setLastRecurringProfileIds($ids);
            // TODO: send recurring profile emails
        }
        Mage::dispatchEvent(
            'checkout_submit_all_after',
            array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $this->getQuote(), 'recurring_profiles' => $profiles)
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**  this script still fails to split the order total, which i am working on and will update you once done
[Here is the code on github,](https://github.com/engrKaka/PMTECH_Ordersplitter) you are welcome to contribute